# Secure Android program for photos?

Tags: android, privacy

Can you please recommend a secure Android app to take photos of sensitive documents?

By secure I mean open-source, reliable/trustworthy.

My stock Android camera app syncs photos to Samsung cloud. This is okay for the most part, but I want to take photos of some documents that I don't want to sync to the cloud. I can turn OFF the sync temporary (and turn ON after transferring away the files), but I'm looking for a dedicated app for sensitive photos. Because with stock app I might forget to turn off sync and accidentally upload the files.

The app (or solution) should allow me to transfer/access the files manually by connecting phone to computer. And also allow a zip Android app to access and zip-up the photos.

Google Play store has many photo apps, but I can't tell which are trustworthy.

Thanks for any suggestions or solutions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you can use **[Open Camera](https://f-droid.org/packages/net.sourceforge.opencamera/).** Please see [my answer here](/a/52518/185) for the general recommendation, and let me focus on your requirement: You will need to separate the photos taken with this "other camera" from those taken with the "stock camera", as otherwise they are just sync'd along¹. *Open Camera* allows you to freely define a directory to store its photos in, but that setting is a bit hard to find: Go to *Settings › More camera controls* and watch out for the item with the floppy-disk symbol. Tap that, and you should see something like this:

[image]
<sup>click image for larger variant</sup>

Toggling on the item "Storage Access Framework" below the disk symbol before tapping it should enable you navigating your entire storage to find a place *outside* `/sdcard/DCIM` which is hopefully save from Samsung's sync.

For a throughout review of the app (comparing it to another candidate, MX Camera), you might wish to see [Camera MX vs Open Camera: Duel of Android Photography Apps](https://www.guidingtech.com/camera-mx-vs-open-camera-comparison/). For a quick getting-started, just take a look at [the app's help page](https://opencamera.sourceforge.io/help.html).

Why especially Open Camera? For one, I'm a happy user of that app. Then, it comes for free and is open source. It's also (one of) the best camera app(s) for Android – certainly the best I've seen so far. And you can get it at the [privacy-focused](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/fdroid-intro-1) [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/)² store³. So I can warmly recommend this one – not just for its offering a freely chosable storage location, but also for its features and its quality.

---

¹ <sub>sync isn't managed by the camera but by Samsung's framework watching the `/sdcard/DCIM` folder, with settings in the Gallery app</sub>
² <sub>disclosure: I'm one of the F-Droid maintainers</sub>
³ <sub>you can also [get it from Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) – but honestly, why should you? ;)</sub>